# Get only nested JSON in Logstash

Tags: logstash

How can I get only nested json in Logstash?

```html
{
    "metadata_1":"Meta 1",
    "metadata_2":"Meta 2",
    ...
    "metadata_N":"Meta N",
    "mydata":{
        "name":"User Name 1",
        "surname":"User SurName 1"
    }
}
```

I want to get only "mydata". All "metadata" must be completely removed from the result.
Logstash config:

```html
input {
    stdin { }
}
filter {
    json {
       source => "message"
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Not worked for me:

```
source => "message"
source => "mydata"
source => "[message][mydata]"
```

The expected result is ("mydata" as root):

```
{
    "name":"User Name 1",
    "surname":"User SurName 1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prune` filter should do what you want:

```
 prune {
   whitelist_names => ["mydata"]
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. That is mostly close to what I'm looking for. But I see that result is not in root, but as "mydata" object. And "prune" does not have "target" field. And chain json filter just after "prune" like: json { source => "mydata" } has no effect.

Comment: Cool! Thanks . .